# React component doesn't render on MUI MenuItem onClick event

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a simple `mui` `Menu`, where one `MenuItem` should render another `React` component. The problem is that my `Menu` is rendered in another file, where `close` and `handleClick` functions are defined.

Problem: The  component doesn't render on the MenuItem click. Seems like it is because `setAnchor(null);` in the `App` component sets the anchor to null always. Does this mean I need to use a different `anchor`? If yes, how?

The Menu component code is as follows:

```
interface Props {
  handler: Handler;
  anchor: HTMLButtonElement | null;
  onClose: () => void;
}

const AddDataMenu = ({ handler,anchor, onClose }: Props) => {
  const renderDataPopOver = () => {
    console.log('this is clicked'); <<<<<<<<<< I can see this function is accessed 
    <AddDataPopover handler={handler} anchor={anchor} onClose={onClose} />;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Menu
        anchorEl={anchor}
        open={Boolean(anchor)}
        onClose={onClose}
        sx={{ width: 320, maxWidth: '100%' }}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={renderDataPopOver}>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <DataIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <Typography>item 1</Typography>
        </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddDataMenu;
```

This is the Main Component where my Menu is rendered.

```
  const App = ({ scope }) => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);

  const [anchor, setAnchor] = useState<HTMLButtonElement | null>(null);
  const [handler, setHandler] = useState<Handler>();

 

  const close = () => {          <<<<<<< this is accessed before MenuItem click
    setAnchor(null);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {    <<<<<<< this is accessed before MenuItem click
    setAnchor(ref.current);
  };


  return showAdd && handler ? (
    <MessageContainer
      message={'test'}
      actions={
        <Box ml={1}>
          <Button ref={ref} color="primary" variant="contained" onClick={handleClick}>
            {t('Visualization.chart-initial-states.AddColumns')}
          </Button>
          <AddDataMenu handler={handler} anchor={anchor} onClose={close} />
        </Box>
      }
    />
  ) : (
    <DisplayError />
  );
};
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the goal is to render a secondary `Popover` beside `Menu` on click of `MenuItem`, perhaps indeed the component would need to assign any `MenuItem` that triggers it as `anchorEl` to the rendered `Popover`.

Basic live example on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-txhbqr?file=src/App.js) (this and below examples omitted everything except for the `Menu` from the original posted code for simplicity).

In `AddDataMenu`, add `AddDataPopover` to the output with its initial `anchorEl` as null so it would not render immediately. Matching `anchorEl` can be assigned in the event of `handleOpen`.

A `ref` array is used to reference multiple `MenuItem` here, but this is an optional approach.

```
const AddDataMenu = ({ anchor, onClose }) => {
  const [itemAnchor, setItemAnchor] = useState(null);
  const itemRef = useRef([]);
  const handleClose = () => {
    setItemAnchor(null);
  };
  const handleOpen = (index) => {
    setItemAnchor(itemRef.current[index]);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Menu
        anchorEl={anchor}
        open={Boolean(anchor)}
        onClose={onClose}
        sx={{
          width: 320,
          maxWidth: '100%',
        }}
      >
        {[1, 2, 3].map((item, index) => (
          <MenuItem
            ref={(node) => (itemRef.current[index] = node)}
            key={index}
            onClick={() => handleOpen(index)}
            sx={{ p: 2 }}
          >
            <ListItemIcon>
              <DataIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <Typography>{`item ${item}`}</Typography>
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Menu>
      <AddDataPopover anchor={itemAnchor} onClose={handleClose} />
    </>
  );
};
```

In `AddDataPopover`, wire up the `anchorEl` to the `Popover` and style the component to be rendered beside active `MenuItem`.

```
const AddDataPopover = ({ anchor, onClose }) => {
  return (
    <Popover
      id={'my-popover'}
      open={Boolean(anchor)}
      anchorEl={anchor}
      onClose={onClose}
      anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: 'center',
        horizontal: 'right',
      }}
      transformOrigin={{
        vertical: 'center',
        horizontal: 'left',
      }}
    >
      <Typography sx={{ p: 2 }}>The content of Data Popover.</Typography>
    </Popover>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I changed my code something similar to what you have suggested. It worked.